# jQuery ProgressBar and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, progress-bar

I use jQuery progressbar in `AJAX` sync request. The Progressbar works fine in FireFox, but it always shows 100% in IE8.

This is my code:

```
var selectRows = $('#rowed3').getGridParam('selarrrow');
$.each(selectRows,function (index,id) {
  $.ajax({                            
          url:'addSign',
          success: function (result) {                                                 
        $("#progressbar").progressbar('option','value',currPercent);
         },
          async:false,
          data:{
          'id':id,
          'details':sign
               },
       type:'post'
});
```

When I add

```
alert('111')
```

before

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar('option','value',currPercent);
```

I have seen Progressbar change its' state.

Why does it not work in IE?

Sorry, but I have skipped some piece of code. I think it's important.

Comment: Open up IE8s console (F12) and post the error messages here

Answer (score 1):

Is Internet Explorer set in Quirks mode? Because usually that messes up the progress bar.

Comment: IE didn't show any errors or warnings. I have create breakpoint. progressbar method was run. But It didn't change progressbar state.

Comment: I have run javascript:alert(document.compatMode). And it showed 'CSS1Compact'. I think it is Standart mode.

Answer (score 0):

check below code..here you have to set "async:true" ...so, your code should be below.

```
var selectRows = $('#rowed3').getGridParam('selarrrow');
$.each(selectRows,function (index,id) {
  $.ajax({                            
          url:'addSign',
          success: function (result) {                                                 
        $("#progressbar").progressbar('option','value',currPercent);
         },
          async:true,
          data:{
          'id':id,
          'details':sign
               },
       type:'post'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution:  [Javascript updates UI only when alert() is used in internet explorer with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215064/javascript-updates-ui-only-when-alert-is-used-in-internet-explorer-with-ajax)

The suggestion with the timeout worked out pretty well for me.