# Javascript updates UI only when alert() is used in internet explorer with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, user-interface

I'm having a problem in Internet Explorer, it works fine with Firefox.

I have a java script function that updates UI (Screen Content) which is called before AJAX function. But it doesn't update UI until an alert box prompt is used. Without alert box it doesn't update UI before AJAX function. It updates UI after AJAX function even if it is called before AJAX function

If i use following code, the UpdateUI() doesn't update the UI at all before AJAX function call, it updates UI after AJAX function call. I want it to update UI before AJAX function call (actually im displaying a loading bar before AJAX call)

```
UpdateUI(); // java script function, it just updates inner HTML of a DIV

// AJAX function call here with Async = false
```

But If i use following code, the UpdateUI() update the UI before AJAX function call, but this method includes an alert prompt. I don't want to use alert

```
UpdateUI(); // java script function, it just updates inner HTML of a DIV

alert('hellow');

// AJAX function call here with Async = false
```

It's working fine in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer 8

Comment: If you're doing a synchronous AJAX call, the browser is probably blocking until it completes. That's one of the reasons synchronous AJAX calls are such a bad idea.

Comment: but then why it works fine in Firefox

Comment: Firefox is a different browser and it works the way the Mozilla people want it to work, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed that your request is sync. Check [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7391) for an explanation (and it's quite close to the answer given by @AshwinPrabhu); yes, it's of jQuery, but it's more about IE7/8 behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Browsers don't usually reflow (refresh) the UI when there is an active JS thread. It waits until it has flushed all events from ts event queue before performing a reflow. Think of this like a single threaded loop in which the browser has to perform all its events.

Reflow usually gets the least priority in certain situations, however you can force the browser to reflow by requesting certain attributes on DOM elements like getComputedStyle or offsetX/y etc. Basically any request that requires the browser to layout the UI to respond will perform a reflow.

[This](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) is the best article I had found sometime back when I was facing a similar problem.

The easiest and fool-proof trick I can suggest is to split your code into two methods and call the method that requires a prior-reflow in a timeout after 0mills. This gives the browser some breather to perform a reflow before it calls method2. This works exactly like the alert() trick you tried and found working.

Comment: Any solution you recommend, I've tried changing many DOM attributes but it didn't worked out  ?

Comment: Brother can you further explain that foll-proof trick. I actually didn't get this trick

Comment: Sure brother. Assuming you want to perform two operations a() and b(), with a reflow before b(). Then do this: a(); window.setTimeout(function(){b();},5); If you need to carry state to b(), then pass them as params to function()

Comment: I've tried exactly what you said. But now my function b(); is not executing

Comment: It must be a bug in your code then. setTimeout executes the first param after specified millis. This is too fundamental and there is no way it cannot work.

Comment: i have even tried an alert prompt on the first line of function that is called in setTimeout, it didn't worked

Comment: You mean like this? window.setTimeout(function(){alert("Hi");},0); - it works. You should open a different question for that. I answered your questions by explaining the reason behind the problem you faced. You will have to manage the specifics of coding yourself.