# Jquery progresbar in IE8 inside an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, kendo-ui

i am facing exactly the same problem as described here: [jQuery ProgressBar and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180678/jquery-progressbar-and-ie8)

I have a jquery progress bar inside an ajax call and update the bar every time i get a response from the server. That works pretty fine on FF but not in IE8 , IE9.

I have noticed too that once i add an alert(); before a new value is set to the progress bar, everything seems to work pretty well then. Once i remove the alert(), nothing really happens.

I could somehow fix the problem by adding an interval, but the results are not as required and surely i cannot put a wait function there and slow down the entire process.

Any suggestions that could maybe help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer finally here:  [Javascript updates UI only when alert() is used in internet explorer with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215064/javascript-updates-ui-only-when-alert-is-used-in-internet-explorer-with-ajax)

The trick with the timeout did the job finally.